# How to make schedule task to run every 3 weeks

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a synchronous scheduled task that has to run every 3 weeks.

For the "Schedule" field, the format is `{start timestamp} | {end timestamp} | {days to run} |{interval}`

the example value can be `20200901|99990101|64|02:00:00`

This would run the task every Saturday every 2 hrs.

Is it possible that if I change this to `20200901|99990101|64|503:59:59` would it run the task every Saturday every 3 weeks. I have added the interval as 504 hrs because its equivalent to 24 hrs * 21 days(that is 3 weeks)

Please recommend if there can be a better solution for the same.

Comment: SiteCron is probably your best option for precision scheduling. Sitecore does not support complex scheduling beyond days in a given week and frequency based on timespan.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve this by Sitecore OOTB task schedulers format

> {start timestamp} | {end timestamp} | {days to run bit pattern}
> |{interval}

You can explore Sitecron module on Sitecore marketplace to achieve complex scheduling using Cron triggers. https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecron

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Windows Task scheduler to execute WebAPI and trigger it via Stecore Powershell extention.

Ref: [Executing Sitecore logic from a Windows Scheduled Task](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/executing-sitecore-logic-from-a-windows-scheduled-task)